# How to interpret the loss function in the categorical generative adversarial net?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

So I've been implementing the categorical generative adversarial networks which is described in [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06390).

[Jost T. Springenberg. Unsupervised and semi-supervised learning with
categorical generative adversarial networks, April 2016.]

[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHWTE.png)

This is the loss function introduced in page 6 and the thing is that the formula uses *arg_max* which is odd because most of the optimizers I can use on various frameworks such as Tensorflow only work in *arg_min*.

So would you please guys tell me how to implement this formula?

Here is the code I implemented.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as Image
# constants
X_dim = 256
Y_dim = 2
Z_dim = 256 * 256
value_lambda = 1.0

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, X_dim, X_dim, 1])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, Y_dim])
Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, Z_dim])

initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer
activation_function = tf.nn.elu
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.5)

custom_filter = np.ones(shape=[32, 256, 256, 1], dtype=np.float)
custom_filter[:, 255, :, :] = 0
custom_filter[:, :, 255, :] = 0

custom_filter = tf.constant(custom_filter, dtype=tf.float32)


def discriminator(x, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name, "discriminator", [x]) as scope:

        D_conv_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=x, filters=16, kernel_size=[
                                    5, 5], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
        # [256, 256]
        D_mean_pool_1 = tf.nn.pool(D_conv_1, window_shape=[
                                   2, 2], pooling_type='AVG', padding='VALID', strides=[2, 2])
        # [128, 128]
        D_conv_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(D_mean_pool_1, filters=32, kernel_size=[
                                    3, 3], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
        # [128, 128]
        D_mean_pool_2 = tf.nn.pool(D_conv_2, window_shape=[
                                   2, 2], pooling_type='AVG', padding='VALID', strides=[2, 2])
        # [64, 64]
        D_conv_3 = tf.layers.conv2d(D_mean_pool_2, filters=64, kernel_size=[
                                    3, 3], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
        # [64, 64]
        D_mean_pool_3 = tf.nn.pool(D_conv_3, window_shape=[
                                   2, 2], pooling_type='AVG', padding='VALID', strides=[2, 2])
        # [32, 32]
        D_conv_4 = tf.layers.conv2d(D_mean_pool_3, filters=128, kernel_size=[
                                    3, 3], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
        # [32, 32]
        D_mean_pool_4 = tf.nn.pool(D_conv_4, window_shape=[
                                   2, 2], pooling_type='AVG', padding='VALID', strides=[2, 2])
        # [16, 16]
        D_conv_5 = tf.layers.conv2d(D_mean_pool_4, filters=256, kernel_size=[
                                    3, 3], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function,  kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
        # [16, 16]
        D_mean_pool_5 = tf.nn.pool(D_conv_5, window_shape=[
                                   4, 4], pooling_type='AVG', padding='VALID', strides=[4, 4])
        # [4, 4]
        D_conv_6 = tf.layers.conv2d(D_mean_pool_5, filters=2, kernel_size=[
                                    3, 3], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function,  kernel_regularizer=regularizer)
        # [4, 4]
        D_mean_pool_6 = tf.nn.pool(D_conv_6, window_shape=[
                                   4, 4], pooling_type='AVG', padding='VALID', strides=[4, 4])
        # [1, 1], and finally, [batch_size][1][1][2]
        D_logit = tf.reshape(D_mean_pool_6, shape=[32, 2])
        # [batch_size][2]

        return D_logit

        '''
        D_hidden_layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(
            inputs=x, units=255, activation=activation_function)
        D_hidden_layer_2 = tf.layers.dense(
            inputs=D_hidden_layer_1, units=16, activation=activation_function)
        D_logit = tf.layers.dense(inputs=D_hidden_layer_2, units=Y_dim,
                                  activation=activation_function)

        return D_logit
        '''


def generator(z, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name, "generator", [z]) as scope:
        # z[32, 4096]
        input = tf.reshape(z, shape=[32, 256, 256, 1])
        # input[32, 64, 64, 1]
        G_conv_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(input, filters=96, kernel_size=[
                                    8, 8], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function)
        # [32, 64, 64, 96]
        # G_upscaled_1 = tf.image.resize_bicubic(images=G_conv_1, size=[128, 128])
        # [32, 128, 128, 96]
        G_conv_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(G_conv_1, filters=64, kernel_size=[
                                    5, 5], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function)
        # [32, 128, 128, 64]
        # G_upscaled_2 = tf.image.resize_bicubic(G_conv_2, size=[256, 256])
        # [32, 256, 256, 64]
        G_conv_3 = tf.layers.conv2d(G_conv_2, filters=64, kernel_size=[
                                    5, 5], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function)
        # [32, 256, 256, 64]
        G_conv_4 = tf.layers.conv2d(G_conv_3, filters=1, kernel_size=[
                                    5, 5], padding='SAME', activation=activation_function)

        # [32, 256, 256, 1]
        G_logit = G_conv_4 * custom_filter
        # [32, 256, 256, 1], but filtered out the last column and row

        return G_logit

        '''
        G_hidden_layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(
            inputs=z, units=255, activation=activation_function)
        G_outputs = tf.layers.dense(inputs=G_hidden_layer_1, units=X_dim,
                                    activation=activation_function)

        return G_outputs
        '''


with tf.name_scope("training") as scope:
    # Getting samples from random data
    G_sample = generator(Z)
    # Getting logits
    D_logit_real = discriminator(X)
    D_logit_fake = discriminator(G_sample)

    # Applying softmax
    D_proba_real = tf.nn.softmax(logits=D_logit_real)
    D_proba_real = tf.clip_by_value(
        D_proba_real, clip_value_min=1e-4, clip_value_max=1.0)
    D_proba_fake = tf.nn.softmax(logits=D_logit_fake)
    D_proba_fake = tf.clip_by_value(
        D_proba_fake, clip_value_min=1e-4, clip_value_max=1.0)

    with tf.name_scope("category_1") as sub_scope:
        # Getting Shannon's entrophy in X's distribution
        D_log_real = tf.log(D_proba_real)
        D_entrophy_real = D_proba_real * D_log_real
        D_mean_real = tf.reduce_sum(D_entrophy_real, axis=1)
        D_mean_real = -D_mean_real
        D_entrophy_real_mean = tf.reduce_mean(D_mean_real, axis=0)
        D_entrophy_real_mean = tf.reshape(D_entrophy_real_mean, shape=[1])

    with tf.name_scope("category_2") as sub_scope:
        # Gettning Shannon's entrophy in Z's distribution
        G_log_fake = tf.log(D_proba_fake)
        G_entrophy_fake = D_proba_fake * G_log_fake
        G_mean = tf.reduce_sum(G_entrophy_fake, axis=1)
        G_mean = -G_mean
        G_entrophy_fake_mean = tf.reduce_mean(G_mean, axis=0)
        G_entrophy_fake_mean = tf.reshape(G_entrophy_fake_mean, shape=[1])

    with tf.name_scope("category_3") as sub_scope:
        # Getting Shannon's entrophy between classes
        D_class_mean = tf.reduce_mean(D_proba_real, axis=0, keep_dims=True)
        D_class_mean_log = tf.log(D_class_mean)
        D_class_entropy = D_class_mean * D_class_mean_log
        D_class = tf.reduce_sum(D_class_entropy, axis=1)
        D_class = -D_class
        D_class = tf.reshape(D_class, shape=[1])

        G_class_mean = tf.reduce_mean(D_proba_fake, axis=0, keep_dims=True)
        G_class_mean_log = tf.log(G_class_mean)
        G_class_entrophy = G_class_mean * G_class_mean_log
        G_class = tf.reduce_sum(G_class_entrophy, axis=1)
        G_class = -G_class
        G_class = tf.reshape(G_class, shape=[1])

    with tf.name_scope("supervised") as sub_scope:
        # Getting cross entrophy for labeled data
        D_labeled = Y * D_log_real
        D_cross_entrophy = tf.reduce_sum(D_labeled, axis=1)
        D_cross_entrophy = -D_cross_entrophy
        D_supervised = tf.reduce_mean(D_cross_entrophy, axis=0)
        D_supervised_weighted = value_lambda * D_supervised
        D_supervised_weighted = tf.reshape(D_supervised_weighted, shape=[1])

    D_loss = D_class - D_entrophy_real_mean + \
        G_entrophy_fake_mean + D_supervised_weighted
    G_loss = -G_class + G_entrophy_fake_mean
    D_loss = -D_loss

    D_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(D_loss)
    G_solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(G_loss)

# with tf.name_scope("testing") as scope:
```

Comment: What have you tried? Let's see some code.

Comment: @Alex Added the code!

Comment: This is a lot of code @user3551261.  What would be helpful is a minimum code set and expected output.  I suspect that what you need is only 2 or 3 lines of code and 2 or 3 lines of example output  If indeed you are asking for arg_max instead of arg_min then an very short example would be much more helpful.  I'd like to help but the prospect of running all the above code you posted is to daunting to start to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research and asked some questions to my friends who works in a big company doing research on deep learning. As it turns out that the generative adversarial networks is not good at classification jobs. So I changed my mind and implemented it with GoogLenet. Problem solved!